# table is changed mutating table problem in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Mutating Table Problem in sql oracle

i have implemented a trigger that prevents the deletion of an account if there is payment.
but I get the error that the table is changed. On the internet it says that it is the mutating table problem.

i just tried with the compound trigger but i couldn't get it to work.

here first the code as it was before

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER checkDelete
BEFORE DELETE ON customerAcc
Declare 
       price NUMBER;
       status NUMBER;
       delete_exception EXCEPTION;  
BEGIN 
SELECT amount, paid INTO price, status FROM payment NATURAL JOIN tutoring
 WHERE customer_ID = :OLD.customer_ID;
IF price != status THEN
RAISE delete_exception;
END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN delete_exception THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Can not delete acc!');
END;
```

and here the code with the compund trigger i tried
the compound trigger I have not completely understood and need help

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER checkDelete
BEFORE DELETE ON customerAcc

Compound Trigger
TYPE r_check_delete is RECORD 
                (
                price NUMBER;
                status NUMBER;
                delete_exception EXCEPTION;
                );


BEFORE EACH ROW IS
BEGIN 
SELECT amount, paid INTO price, status FROM payment NATURAL JOIN tutoring
 WHERE customer_ID = :OLD.customer_ID;
IF price != status THEN
RAISE delete_exception;
END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN delete_exception THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Can not delete acc!');
END BEFORE EACH ROW;
END;
```

Comment: I somehow still did not get it right. Can someone help

Answer (score 0):

It is not *just* about declaring the trigger to be compound.  We use the compound nature of the trigger to break the task into 2 part

1. before each row

Keep a record in memory (eg in a PLSQL table) of the details for the row(s) that are being modified, but we do NOT run any DML because that would yield mutating table errors

2. after statement

Use that list of rows to now go back and run the DML that you intended to do at the row level but could not. Because the main DML (that fired the trigger) has completed, you are now seeing the table in a consistent state.

You can see a full walkthrough of the issue, the workarounds and the locking implications at a video I made here

https://youtu.be/hdU92bsByOQ

Comment: I somehow still did not get it right.  I think the video dont help me. can you show me it on this example